# How to create a cookie that is accessible from every folders

Tags: javascript, cookies

so i have a code like that

```
function createCookie(cname, cvalue, ctime) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (ctime*24*60*60*1000));
  var perime = "perime="+date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + perime + "domain=.main.html;path=/";
}
```

and i dont know why my cookies are not accessible to other folders than the one who create the cookie :C can you give me a little help ?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `path=/` part from the cookie, like this.

```
function createCookie(cname, cvalue, ctime) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (ctime*24*60*60*1000));
  var perime = "perime="+date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + perime + ";";
}
```

and am not really sure about the domain, as a file isn't a domain.